# Bootstrap theme has different margins in different browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the xeon Bootstrap template (http://shapebootstrap.net/preview/?id=64).  Firefox on a Mac renders the margins close to the edge of the window.  Safari, using a window that is exactly the same size, renders the margins much wider.

Two questions:  Why is this?  How can I configure Bootstrap to be more consistent across browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the margin for a `.container` element?

Comment: I think so.  If you look at the link I provided with two both Safari and Firefox, you'll see a lot more margin or padding on the left and right in Safari.  Those elements seem to be in a container div, but I'm not sure why they'd render so differently.

Comment: Firefox 35.0.1 and Safari 5.1.7 appear to have identical page widths and side margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on a Mac so I cannot verify what I'm about to suggest. A screenshot might be helpful or a link to the page. There is not a lot to go on here, hence the lack of answers, but I'll give it a shot.

I'm assuming the issue is with the browsers and not Bootstrap or some sort of perception of difference that is not fully understood.

What exactly do you mean by *"is exactly the same size"*? Are both browsers maximized? Did you manually re-size them so the top, right, bottom and left edges line up? If so, that doesn't mean the viewports are the same size. Each browser has it's own chrome, UI elements (scrollbar) and etc., that can be different sizes and which will affect the viewport size.

The `.container` element's margin is set to `auto` which the browser automatically calculates for set width elements like `.container`. Bootstrap's `.container` class has specified widths for various viewport sizes. You might be viewing your page at a viewport width that is very close to a breakpoint and the right scrollbar (or something similar) is slightly smaller/larger in one browser than in the other. This in turn could trigger the page to render at a different widths giving the appearance of different margins.

For example:

Bootstrap has a breakpoint at 992px.

- If your viewport width is 995px in Firefox, Bootstrap would render `.container` at 970px.
- If your viewport width is 990px in Safari, Bootstrap would render `.container` at 750px.

Based on this suggestion of it being a breakpoint issue I would find out what each browser's viewport width is exactly. Then make sure you set them to the same width. If you get the same result/issue, then you will know it is not a breakpoint.

Additional information would be helpful.

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably what's happening.  Here's what I see in Safari: http://imgur.com/GwXvZto and here's what I see in Firefox: http://imgur.com/plifB52.  As you can see, Firefox has more content displayed.

Comment: Most likely, I see two columns in the Safari screenshot below the header/slider and three columns in the Firefox screenshot. If you believe this to be the correct answer please accept it as so.